# isNewRecord is always false

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize model called `Test` with a unique field `value` (primary key). I'm using SQLite as the database management system.

When I use the `bulkCreate()` option `ignoreDuplicates: true`, then `bulkCreate` ignores the new data if it already exists in the database. That works but the objects returned by `bulkCreate()` always have `isNewRecord: false`, even when a new record was inserted into the database.

### Code

```js
const items = [ {value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'} ]; // Items to be saved in database.

const results = await Test.bulkCreate(items, {
    ignoreDuplicates: true // Ignore duplicate records
});
```

After first execution of `bulkCreate()` on empty database, the value of `results`:

```
[
  Test {
    dataValues: {
      value: 'a',
      createdAt: 2020-07-12T12:01:08.695Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-07-12T12:01:08.695Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      value: 'a',
      createdAt: 2020-07-12T12:01:08.695Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-07-12T12:01:08.695Z
    },
    _changed: Set {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: true,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      include: undefined
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  Test {
    dataValues: {
      value: 'b',
      createdAt: 2020-07-12T12:01:08.695Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-07-12T12:01:08.695Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      value: 'b',
      createdAt: 2020-07-12T12:01:08.695Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-07-12T12:01:08.695Z
    },
    _changed: Set {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: true,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      include: undefined
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

I expected `isNewRecord: true` after the first execution. What am I missing?

### Environment

- Windows 10 Pro
- NodeJS v12.16.2
- Sequelize v6.3.3
- SQLite3 v5.0.0

### Sequelize docs

`isNewRecord` of [`Model`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html):

[image]

`ignoreDuplicates` of [`bulkCreate()`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to access `_options.isNewRecord`.

As this [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9846) states that the `isNewRecord` only be set to true if the instance has not yet been persisted to the database.

In your case, because you have saved the instance (the first time or second time, it doesn't matter, you already save it) so `isNewRecord` is set to false.

So as I mention above, if you want to check if your instance is just saved the first time or not, access `_options.isNewRecord`.

Comment: where is `_options` ?

Comment: It is inside the `results` variable, returned from sequelize query

Comment: FYI: `_options` is not accessible if you use `{raw: true}`

Answer (score 3):

The `isNewRecord` field is true if the Model instance does not exist in the database.

```
const user = new User({ ...userData });
console.log(user.isNewRecord); // true
await user.save();
console.log(user.isNewRecord); // false
```